# Flash Builder conditional compilation variables

Tags: actionscript, compiler-construction, flash-builder, conditional-compilation

I'm using Flash Builder 4.5 and I'd like to use conditional compilation between my debug and release builds.

I understand how to use conditional compilation and how to define compiler constants.
What I need is either:

- A predefined constant set by the IDE between debug and release builds
- A way to specify different arguments for the compiler between debug and release builds

Using ANT is not an option as of now (no time!) and changing the variables by hand every time is just too risky.

Answer (score 0):

ant is not very complicated use for building as3 stuff. 
I use conditional compiling + different build targets for release and debug, with different file endings and such. It also makes it easier to use with a CI server.
You can continue to use the ide for all debug builds, but when you actually want to release, you just build the appropriate ant target. And never have to remember to switch.

FB has built in support for building ant targets, that makes this even easier.