# Is there any way of only embedding certain assets at compile time?

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air

I have a x-platform AIR project set up in FlashDevelop. 
The same code-base can publish out to either an iOS or android target. 
I'm using Adobe's Texture Format (ATF) for compressed texture atlases and at the moment I'm embedding all compressed files within each atf container file (so it includes textures for desktop, iOS and android GPU chipsets)

My problem is our app contains many texture atlases and obviously we want to keep the download to a minimum, so I would like to compress for different targets separately (i.e. there will be an atf file which will only have the pvrtc compression for iOS, and another one which only contains the etc1 compression for android) and only include the compatible file for each platform.

The question is nothing to do with ATF or compression however - I have this all working.

What i would like to know is : is there a solution for only including the necessary (target compatible) files at compile time?

I'm currently using Embed metadata to include the .atf file and I'm under the impression metadata can't be modified dynamically at compile time (i.e. to switch the embed source from xxx_ios.atf to xxx_android.atf depending on which target is selected)

I suppose there could be other solutions, i.e. using a loader at runtime and only including the appropriate asset folder at compile time using an argument in the adt compiler, but it's not ideal - a simple switch which could embed a list of files at compile time would be much better/more elegant I think, especially if i could make this purely dynamic so it's configured/included by the project's target rather than having to manually switch an import statement.

Any ideas on the best way of achieving this?

Thanks

Comment: You could compile each targets assets into seperate SWCs (ie one each for desktop, ios, android). Then include the appropriate SWC depending on the publishing target.

Comment: That would indeed work Lee, Cheers. In this instance I have found out it might not be the way to go (as all embedded assets will load into system memory with the main swf - not a great idea on mobile) and have decided to load assets in at runtime instead. But yeah I think the compiled swc and linkage is obviously an elegeant solution rather than using embed metadata

Comment: if you were using Flash Builder, i would suggest this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178316/flash-builder-conditional-compilation-variables - maybe there's something similar for Flash Develop? Or it may even work the same way if FD compiles in same way as FB does

Answer (score 1):

Conditional compilation is one way to get this done when using embeds:

```
  CONFIG::IOS {
    [Embed(source="foo_ios.atf", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
      private var foo:Class;
  }

  CONFIG::ANDROID {
    [Embed(source="foo_android.atf", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
      private var foo:Class;
  }
```

Or if you decide to use loaders (though you'd have to modify the build to include only the proper assets directories.)

```
CONFIG::IOS {
  var url:String = "foo_ios.atf"
}

CONFIG::ANDROID {
  var url:String = "foo_android.atf"
}
```

Then you need to modify your build options with the following defines (note that you have to define both, setting one to true and one to false).  There's a menu in Flash Develop for this (see [Flash Develop article](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3_Conditional_Compilation), specifically the `User-defined constants` section in the middle), but here are the compiler commands that you'll define:

For iOS:

```
mxmlc Main.as -define=CONFIG::IOS,true -define=CONFIG::ANDROID,false
```

For Andorid:

```
mxmlc Main.as -define=CONFIG::IOS,false -define=CONFIG::ANDROID,true
```

Alternately, you could also symlink (for Mac/Linux) or copy (for Windows) your `assets` directory from either `assets_ios` or `assets_android` before running the build.  This is a pre-processing solution (if you prefer to avoid complicating your build), there are surely others.  You can muck around with Flash Develop's .bat files to make it run pre-processing steps before the build.